# How do I retrieve data from UI5's rich text editor and use it in my controller?

Tags: sapui5

I was wondering is it possible to type text into the rich text editor in UI5 and then get that text in your controller. I am including my rich text editor through my controller like this

```
oEditor: {
            oRichTextEditor: new RichTextEditor("myRTE", {
                editorType: sap.ui.richtexteditor.EditorType.TinyMCE4,
                width: "100%",
                height: "600px",
                customToolbar: true,
                showGroupFont: true,
                showGroupLink: true,
                showGroupInsert: true,
                value: "",
                ready: function () {
                    this.addButtonGroup("styleselect").addButtonGroup("table");
                }
            })
        },
```

and I adding it to the view using `this.getView().byId("editor").addContent(this.oEditor.oRichTextEditor);`

The view I am adding it to is

```
<l:VerticalLayout id="editor" class="sapUiContentPadding" width="100%"></l:VerticalLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes,it's possible you can get the rich text editor content and set it for example into the textArea, for your information the content of the rich text editor contains the HTML editor tags.

```
 GetContent : function() {
                    // get the rich text control by id 
                    var richText = this.getView().byId("solTextArea");
                    //textarea to set the content you get from the richtext
                    var textArea = this.getView().byId("textArea");
                    textArea.setValue(richText.getValue());
                }
```